How To Convert String To Int32?
$a = '1'
$b = 1
$a.GetType().Name
$b.GetType().Name

The Output:
String
Int32

How do I convert $a to Int32?
I mean like $b = 1
The following does not work:
$a.ToType(Int32)
$a.ToType('Int32')


How to convert $a to Int32?
Use [Int]$a:

Convert the Strings to Numbers Using [Int]
But what if we need to add these two numbers together rather than just
performing a string join (i.e., concatenating them)? The simplest way
to deal with this is by typing [Int] before each variable name. This
forces PowerShell to treat the values as integers rather than strings.

Source: How To Convert PowerShell String Data to Integers
See also: PowerShell: Converting String Representations of Numbers to Integers - Stack Overflow

Use $a = '1' -as [Int].
Example:
> $a = '1' -as [Int]
> $a.GetType().Name
Int32
> $a | gm

   TypeName: System.Int32

Name        MemberType Definition
----        ---------- ----------
CompareTo   Method     int CompareTo(System.Object value), int CompareTo(int value), int IComparable.CompareTo(System.Object obj), int IComparable[int].CompareTo(int other)
Equals      Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj), bool Equals(int obj), bool IEquatable[int].Equals(int other)
GetHashCode Method     int GetHashCode()
GetType     Method     type GetType()
GetTypeCode Method     System.TypeCode GetTypeCode(), System.TypeCode IConvertible.GetTypeCode()
ToBoolean   Method     bool IConvertible.ToBoolean(System.IFormatProvider provider)
ToByte      Method     byte IConvertible.ToByte(System.IFormatProvider provider)
ToChar      Method     char IConvertible.ToChar(System.IFormatProvider provider)
ToDateTime  Method     datetime IConvertible.ToDateTime(System.IFormatProvider provider)
ToDecimal   Method     decimal IConvertible.ToDecimal(System.IFormatProvider provider)
ToDouble    Method     double IConvertible.ToDouble(System.IFormatProvider provider)
ToInt16     Method     short IConvertible.ToInt16(System.IFormatProvider provider)
ToInt32     Method     int IConvertible.ToInt32(System.IFormatProvider provider)
ToInt64     Method     long IConvertible.ToInt64(System.IFormatProvider provider)
ToSByte     Method     sbyte IConvertible.ToSByte(System.IFormatProvider provider)
ToSingle    Method     float IConvertible.ToSingle(System.IFormatProvider provider)
ToString    Method     string ToString(), string ToString(string format), string ToString(System.IFormatProvider provider), string ToString(string format, System.IFormatProvider provider), string IC…
ToType      Method     System.Object IConvertible.ToType(type conversionType, System.IFormatProvider provider)
ToUInt16    Method     ushort IConvertible.ToUInt16(System.IFormatProvider provider)
ToUInt32    Method     uint IConvertible.ToUInt32(System.IFormatProvider provider)
ToUInt64    Method     ulong IConvertible.ToUInt64(System.IFormatProvider provider)
TryFormat   Method     bool TryFormat(System.Span[char] destination, [ref] int charsWritten, System.ReadOnlySpan[char] format, System.IFormatProvider provider), bool ISpanFormattable.TryFormat(Syste…

>


Thanks, Sir. I search the member of $a with $a | gm, and not found [Int]...

@Mr.Key7 Answer updated.

Thanks for other options format writing: $a -as [Int] and [Int]$a
